Why add nop instruction in __turn_mmu_on?
        mcr p15, 0, r5, c3, c0, 0       @ load domain access register
        mcr p15, 0, r4, c2, c0, 0       @ load page table pointer
        b   __turn_mmu_on
    
        .align  5
        .type   __turn_mmu_on, %function
    __turn_mmu_on:
        mov r0, r0
        mcr p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0       @ write control reg
        mrc p15, 0, r3, c0, c0, 0       @ read id reg
        mov r3, r3
        mov r3, r3
        mov pc, r13

why there is nop instruction?just wait for precede instruction to complete
mcr p15, 0, r5, c3, c0, 0       @ load domain access register
mcr p15, 0, r4, c2, c0, 0       @ load page table pointer

but branch instruction will flush remaining instruction in pipeline? so what is the propose for nop (mov r0, r0)?
mov r0, r0

just like nop,it will do nothing.If i remove the code,what will happen?mmu will work well?
where can i find orignal code？
00945010c063b (Russell King 2010-10-04 17:56:13 +0100 501) mov r0, r0

i get it from git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
when i ask git ,it offer the information below
^1da177e4c3f (Linus Torvalds 2005-04-16 15:20:36 -0700 197) mov r0, r0


TL;DR - the nop has no intended outcome in calculating a value (direct functional impact).  It is used to schedule the MCR and subsequent operations.  This scheduling is for a wide variety of devices.

The original ARM mmu code had a 'dance of death'.  There are also additional details in this question.
The nop instructions are 'time' padding to ensure that the MMU is actually turned on before the branch instruction.  An isb could be used in the case of code updates.  However, the MMU is changing the instruction space, but this change is outside the scope of the CPU.
__turn_mmu_on is generic to several ARM CPUs and the latency to actually turn on the MMU and the mcr instruction can vary.  The initial mov r0,r0 could be for alignment of subsequent instructions.  When you have questions, you can ask git.  git blame head.S...

00945010c063b (Russell King          2010-10-04 17:56:13 +0100 501)     mov     r0, r0

In my variant, there is an 'instr_sync' as well.  This commit is due to a copy.  If you follow that it goes to the initial git commit of Linux.
We also have this question as well, where considerations for the XScale are a consideration.

If i remove the code, what will happen? mmu will work well?

Who knows?  It depends on the particular CPU.  The Linux code is crafted to work with a wide variety of ARM CPUs including some very old pre-2000 designs.  You will likely break one of these if you remove it.
For certain, the MMU will work well.  It may just crash your code and brick your device or you will be a hero and save four bytes of code.
Here is the current code,
/*
 * Enable the MMU.  This completely changes the structure of the visible
 * memory space.  You will not be able to trace execution through this.
 * If you have an enquiry about this, *please* check the linux-arm-kernel
 * mailing list archives BEFORE sending another post to the list.
 *
 *  r0  = cp#15 control register
 *  r1  = machine ID
 *  r2  = atags or dtb pointer
 *  r9  = processor ID
 *  r13 = *virtual* address to jump to upon completion
 *
 * other registers depend on the function called upon completion
 */
        .align  5
        .pushsection    .idmap.text, "ax"
ENTRY(__turn_mmu_on)
        mov     r0, r0
        instr_sync
        mcr     p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0           @ write control reg
        mrc     p15, 0, r3, c0, c0, 0           @ read id reg
        instr_sync
        mov     r3, r3
        mov     r3, r13
        ret     r3
__turn_mmu_on_end:
ENDPROC(__turn_mmu_on)
        .popsection

Mainly this is extremely tricky code.  You can not step through it; or it won't behave the same when not stepping through.  It works on a WIDE variety of ARM CPUs, including Thumb-2 devices.  It is quite possible that for a particular CPU type, it is not needed.  It is almost impossible for anyone to test it on all the support ARM devices  (especially for four bytes of code (or two in Thumb2 mode)).

In fact, the 'instr_sync' macro is an isb instructions on CPUs that support that opcode.  The __turn_mmu_on code is doubly mapped in existing (PC relative boot) and target kernel address.  Note also, the r0 is being manipulated in __enable_mmu which jumps here.

Often MCR instructions do not have an immediate effect.  These are the rationale for subsequent nop like instructions.  The initial nop is for alignment, or timing

where do you get kernel code?i get it from git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
^1da177e4c3f (Linus Torvalds    2005-04-16 15:20:36 -0700 197)  mov     r0, r0 i want to get the original code,but i don't know where  to get

The mov pc, lr is equivalent to the "sub pc, pc, #4" (they are defined to be the same class of instructions), so merely adding one instruction should guarantee that the Xscale works as expected.+    sub    pc, pc, #4                @ nop when in this instruction Write-back pipeline,it will update pc to the next instruction,but next instruction mov pc, lr is in Buffer/data pipeline,what will happen next cycle?just update pc to lr and fetch instruction mov pc, lr then cancel it?so sub    pc, pc, #4 is nop ,it will nothing.

Before the ret r3, the runtime address is not the kernel absolute address. It runs from any address (where ever the loader puts it).  It don't know what the last comment about mov pc,lr is referring to.  However, it is important that on some systems, the address that __turn_mmu_on initially executes at is not necessarily the link address.  This is why the code in 'head.S' is all PC relative (and coded in assembler).  The MMU will map the code to it's final address in virtual space.
